# Problema de sobreposição de sessões com ancoras em html

Tags: html5, css3, menu, link

pessoal estou fazendo um [site](http://www.deepocean.com.br/approved/) que possui um menu com ancoras, todas funcionam bem menos a ancora do menu chamada equipe notem que ela desce certinho para sessão porem ela sobrepõem todo o  titulo sendo que nas outras sessões funciona corretamente porque isso acontece ?

Quando eu clico tinha que ficar assim
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

mais está ficando assim:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

OBS: link do site no inicio do tópico

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Kirito repare que em todas as outra sessões do seu sitem exite um `padding:100px` mas na sessão da ***Equipe (parallax)*** não existe esse padding por isso está se sobrepondo.

Basta acrescentar isso nos CSS que vai resolver:

```
section#count_parallax {
    padding: 100px 0;
}
```

Veja o resultado na imagem, repare no Box vermelho:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]